# cannot import name 'xxx' from partially initialized moduleの発生条件

Tags: python

## 概要

パッケージ内でファイルをimportする実験のため、
下記の構成にて`m.py`を実行すると、エラー `cannot import name 'xxx' from partially initialized module`が発生しました。

しかし`__init__.py`の行の順番を入れ替えるとエラーが消滅し、正常に動作します。

### ファイル内容

#### __init__.py

```py
from tsmod.m import ModuleM
from tsmod.p import ModuleP
```

#### m.py

```py
from tsmod import ModuleP


class ModuleM:
    pass
```

#### p.py

```py
class ModuleP:
    pass
```

### ディレクトリ構成

```
tsmod
 L __init__.py
 L m.py
 L p.py
```

## 実行条件

### 実行環境

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Pythonバージョン: 3.8.5

PyCharm2021.1.2にて実行
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### コマンド

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/USER/XXX/XXXX/tsmod/m.py
```

### エラー内容

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/XXX/XXXX/tsmod/m.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tsmod import ModuleP
  File "/home/USER/XXX/XXXX/tsmod/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tsmod.m import ModuleM
  File "/home/USER/XXX/XXXX/tsmod/m.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tsmod import ModuleP
ImportError: cannot import name 'ModuleP' from partially initialized module 'tsmod' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/USER/XXX/XXXX/tsmod/__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### __init__.py (正常動作版)

１行目と２行目を入れ替え。

```py
from tsmod.p import ModuleP
from tsmod.m import ModuleM
```

## 疑問

1. なぜエラーが発生しているのか？
2. なぜ`__init__.py`の順番を入れ替えることでエラーが消滅するのか？

## 補足

pycharm上でなくターミナルにて`m.py`を実行した場合、ModuleNotFoundErrorが出ました。

### コマンド

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/USER/XXX/XXXX/tsmod/m.py
```

### エラー内容

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/XXX/XXXX/tsmod/m.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tsmod import ModuleP
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tsmod'
```

Comment: 実行状況とエラー内容を追記しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. なぜエラーが発生しているのか？**

状況とエラーメッセージ内容を見ると、メッセージに書いてある通り`circular import`が発生しているためでしょう。

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ModuleP' from partially initialized module 'tsmod' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/USER/XXX/XXXX/tsmod/__init__.py)
```

cannot import name 'ModuleP' from partially initialized module 'tsmod'
→部分的に初期化されたモジュール「tsmod」から名前「ModuleP」をインポートできません。

---

(Ubuntu上の?)PyCharmでモジュール内のあるスクリプトを実行すると、モジュールをインポートしたように見えるのは謎ですが、エラーのスタックトレースを見る限り以下のような状況でしょう。

1. `m.py`の1行目の`from tsmod import ModuleP`が処理される
2. `tsmod`モジュールの`__init__.py`の1行目の`from tsmod.m import ModuleM`が処理される
3. この時点で`tsmod`モジュールの情報が(おそらくモジュール名だけ)部分的にPythonに登録される
4. `m.py`の1行目の`from tsmod import ModuleP`が処理される
5. Pythonに登録された部分的な`tsmod`モジュール情報内に`ModuleP`が存在しないのでエラーになる

---

**2. なぜ`__init__.py`の順番を入れ替えることでエラーが消滅するのか？**

`__init__.py`内の行を逆にすると、以下のように動作すると思われます。

1. `m.py`の1行目の`from tsmod import ModuleP`が処理される
2. `tsmod`モジュールの`__init__.py`の1行目の`from tsmod.p import ModuleP`が処理される
3. `p.py`の`ModuleP`が処理され、`tsmod`モジュールに登録される
4. `tsmod`モジュールの`__init__.py`の2行目の`from tsmod.m import ModuleM`が処理される
5. `m.py`の1行目の`from tsmod import ModuleP`が処理される
6. `tsmod`モジュールには既に`ModuleP`が登録されているので、正常にインポートされる
7. `m.py`の`ModuleM`が処理され、`tsmod`モジュールに登録される
8. この時点で`tsmod`モジュールの情報が完全にPythonに登録される==`__init__.py`の処理が終了する
9. `m.py`の`ModuleM`が処理され、`tsmod`モジュールに登録される？？？(どうなっているかは不明)

---

そしておそらく @oriri さん回答のように`from tsmod.p import ModuleP`とした場合は、以下のようにPython上に登録された情報ではなく`p.py`ファイルを直接見に行くのでしょう。

1. `m.py`の1行目の`from tsmod.p import ModuleP`が処理される
2. `tsmod`フォルダ？の`p.py`が読み込まれて`ModuleP`が処理・登録される
3. `m.py`の`ModuleM`が処理・登録される

---

例えば`__init__.py`を含む各ファイルの各行の前後・間に`print('何か挿入箇所の位置情報')`を挿入してどの順番で実行されているかを調べると、状況が分かると思われます。

---

こちらの記事等を参考に`circular import`となるような設計は見直した方が良いでしょう。
[python import動作](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73880/26370)

Answer (score 0):

たぶん `m.py` 部分かも？ (以下のように修正すれば OK)

```py
from tsmod import ModuleP
```

```py
from tsmod.p import ModuleP
```

行の入れ替え前でも, 入れ替え後でも, 同様にエラーになりそうに思えるけど,
Pythonでは, 実際にモジュールを必要とするまで loadを遅延する機能があり,
先に `ModuleP` を読み込んだあとでの, `m.py`内の `import`は保留されたのかもしれない？
(動作の詳細は分かりません)

---

(VS Code の Python拡張では, このような `import` 指定ミスは警告？が出ます)
(その様な機能を持つ エディターか開発環境を活用し, 問題特定に繋げると便利です)